# Swap Column Values Within One Row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to swap two column within only one row.

For example, we have such a table:

```
Table T:
row #    A  |  B  |  C
        ---------------
  1      1  |  2  |  3
  2      5  |  4  |  6
  3      7  |  8  |  9
```

I am trying to swap two values in row #2, I want to change `5, 4, 6` to `4, 5, 6` without affecting the other columns. The result should be like this:

```
Table T:
row #    A  |  B  |  C
        ---------------
  1      1  |  2  |  3
  2      4  |  5  |  6
  3      7  |  8  |  9
```

What should I do using SQL?

Follow up:

This question is raised when I want to sort within a row. The A, B, C can be regarded as three points that made up a triangle. To avoid the repetition, I would like to sort the A, B, C to the order of small to large. That is why I am asking how to swap the value within the rows without affecting the others.

Now I indeed find the way to sort the numbers but with brute force `UNION` and renaming the result under each circumstance like when `A > B > C` or `B > A > C` and so on.

Comment: Are those your only columns? Do you have an "id" column or some sort of primary key column to identify the row to change, beside the values of a/b/c?

Comment: And do you actually want to make the change in your table, or just in a select result?

Comment: I would like to change the table not the select result. Actually, this problem is raised when I tried to sort the columns within the row. Suppose we have a row of `2,1,3`, then I would like to sort it to `1,2,3` without changing the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following query:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over () = 2 THEN T.B ELSE T.A END AS A1,
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over () = 2 THEN T.A ELSE T.B END AS B2,
  T.C
FROM T;
```

Returns your expected result:

```
         A  |  B  |  C
        ---------------
  1      1  |  2  |  3
  2      5  |  4  |  6
  3      7  |  8  |  9
```

**Note:** This doesn't change the data in the database. Rather, it just displays the data in a different way.

--

**Update:** Full working example in the following sandbox:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vYiCubo6CHMayqsjvzo5nD/4

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I indeed would like to change the data in the database. Maybe I have to find a way to circumvent the swapping problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET
  A = LEAST(A, B, C),
  C = GREATEST (A, B, C),
  B = CASE 
        WHEN A > LEAST(A, B, C) AND A < GREATEST (A, B, C) THEN A
        WHEN C > LEAST(A, B, C) AND C < GREATEST (A, B, C) THEN C
        ELSE B
      END
WHERE NOT (A <= B AND B <= C);
```

it uses `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` to get the values for `A` and `C` 
and `CASE` to check which is the intermediate value for `B`.

Answer (score 0):

If you [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) extension, this is quite easy:

```
update t
   set a = (sort(array[a,b,c]))[1],
       b = (sort(array[a,b,c]))[2],
       c = (sort(array[a,b,c]))[3]
;
```